# How to interpret this binomial distribution result?

Tags: binomial-distribution

From the Binomial distribution, the chance of getting at least 50 heads when flipping a fair coin 100 times is 54% (to 1 d.p.). It seems to imply that that there will be more heads than tails, but this contradicts the common sense conclusion that the number of heads and tails will be equal, on average. And of course, by symmetry, the same applies to tails. I'm Confused.

Comment: From https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx. Field 1 enter 0.5, field 2 enter 100, field 3 enter 50. Result of P(X >= x) = 0.5397946187.

Comment: Let $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p=.5).$ then $P(X \ge 50) = P(X > 49) \approx 0.54$ and $P(X \ge 51) = P(X \le 49) \approx 0.46.$ Also, $P(X=50)\approx 0.08.$  R code: `sum(dbinom(50:100, 100, .5))` returns $0.5397946$
`sum(dbinom(51:100, 100, .5))` returns $0.4602054$ and `dbinom(50,100, .5)` returns $0.07958924.$ // Be careful about "at least" and "greater than". // I think @whuber assumes you are using normal approximation to binomial, which I guess is the method intended by your textbook problem.

Comment: Normal aprx: $P(X \le 49) = P(X < 49.5) = P\left(Z < \frac{49.5-50}{\sqrt{25}}\right) \approx 0.4602$ from R code `pnorm((49.5-50)/sqrt(25))`. Without "continuity correction," it would be $P(X < 50)=P\left(Z < \frac{50-50}{\sqrt{25}}\right)=1/2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we include the possibility of flipping 50 heads in the analysis, we include an event outcome in which heads does not exceed tails (50 of each). Try instead breaking up the event sample space into three categories: heads exceeds tails (H>50), tails exceeds heads (H<50), and heads equals tails (H=T=50).

Comment: Yes, those 3 probabilities do sum to 1, as expected. But why does P(X >= 50) not sum to 0.5? Doesn't P(X >= 50) mean P(X=50) + P(X=51) + P(X=52) +...+ P(X=100)?

Comment: Because it includes the probability of equals heads and tails. You essentially have three sample spaces, two of which are symmetric (more heads than tails and more tails than heads) plus a third space (equal heads and tails). You are combining two of those spaces: more heads than tails and equal heads and tails; if you compare that space to more tails than heads and equal tails and heads, they will be equal but you will be counting an equal number of heads and tails twice therefore combining P(H>=50) and P(T>=50) will be greater than 100%.

Comment: Duh, of course. Thanks.